# tools to hide ip and mac address

Tags: windows-xp, networking, ip-address, mac-address

Are there any fast and free software to:

1. Hide my IP address without proxy server as it changes the layout of the web site and makes it not fast at all.
2. Dynamic MAC address generator to change it continuously or a tool to hide the MAC address.

Because I have problems with many users - it cuts my connection and decreases my Internet connection speed.

I have tried programs like anti-ARP and anti-netcut, but still these problems exists.

Comment: what operating system..?

Comment: windows xp ....

Comment: What exactly is the goal of these actions? I dont think your connection will get any faster if you change your mac or hide your ip address.

Comment: what i think about not the speed , i try to prevent any attack or cut for my connection ,so if i hide my ip and mac address , i imagine this will limit the cuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see that being possible.  You have to have a valid IP address and MAC on the network in order to communicate.  'Hiding' either would basically mean that as far as the network was concerned, you had neither, which would mean you wouldn't be able to communicate.

A decent firewall (like ZoneAlarm) is all I can recommend, but that won't stop people on the local network hijacking your IP or MAC address.